# getting a "CRITICAL Call to a member function set_messages() on null" when trying to checkout on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am using Woocommerce (version 3.3.1) and Strip integration and the latest version of Wordpress (4.9.4). There was an update a couple of weeks ago and when I click "place order" on my checkout page, I get an error "Payment Failed - Please Try Again Later"

I am using the Stripe Plugin for Woocommerce as well.

I checked the Woocommerce > Status > Log section and keep getting these two following errors:

> 2018-02-13T13:11:44+00:00 CRITICAL Call to a member function
>   set_messages() on null
>
> 2018-02-13T13:20:23+00:00 CRITICAL Call to undefined method
>   WooCommerce::add_inline_js()

I'm not that familiar with these errors and am not sure where to begin to look, but this is obviously the problem.

I'm fairly convinced the error is with the Woocommerce strip gateway rather than just Woocommerce because I can do an "Order Test" and this goes through fine.

Would anyone be able to provide guidance? I would post the code but I'm not even sure what file the error is in.

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.3.1, I will add that to the original question thanks for clarifying that

Comment: @logos_164 Woocommerce 3.3.1 is a recent **major** update and is still with some bugs. Also a lot of themes and plugins are not ready to be used with it. You should roll back to stable 3.2.6 version that you can find [**HERE at the end of the page**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/advanced/) within the selector dropdown. **Always wait some time (2 or 3 month) for major woocommerce updates on production web site**.

Comment: Good advice, I actually ended up backing the update up before I saw this but thank you for responding, I'm going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not a full answer because it doesn't solve the engineering problem, but essentially what I ended up doing was reverting back to the Stripe Payment Gateway Version 3.2.3 as the updates conflict with the current theme.

[Stripe Payment Gateway Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe)